# Reload grid does not refresh search filter toolbars

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

On using:

```
$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

The search filter toolbar doesnt get refreshed. However the Refresh button on pager refreshes everything.

What should I use to trigger the entire grid to refresh including searchfilter toolbar. Please help. Thanks

I am using loadonce set to default. datatype is json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reloadGrid` reloads the content of the page based on the filter, sort order, the page size and the page number. If you need ignore the filter then you have to clear the filter *before* triggering of `reloadGrid`:

```
var $grid = $("#grid"), postData = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
postData.filters = ""; // or delete postData.filters;
$grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: 1}]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Oleg That works perfectly. However there is a situation, I shouldnt reload. I can clear the filters by the first two lines of your code itself. However, without refrshing, I am trying to restoreRow, it doesnt restoreRow, any idea why its happening? I am clearing filters, not reloading grid, instead trying to restore one row. But not restoring the row. Please help.

Comment: @MattMurdock: You are welcome! The problem with `restoreRow` seems be absolutely independent from your current question. It's better that you ask *separate* question, where you describe the problem clear. The method `restoreRow` belong to subset of *inline editing* methods. It can be used only if you call it to the row, which is currently in editing mode (after calling of `editRow`). Moreover it's mostly important to know which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS or an old jqGrid vers.<4.7).

Comment: Thanks @Oleg. I got it work somehow using beforeSearch event. One more question. how to prevent Refreshing jqgrid in beforeRefresh event? like we can stop search filter in beforeSearch event. Please help.

Comment: @MattMurdock: `beforeRefresh` don't allow to stop refreshing. I'd recommend you to use `refresh: false` option of `navGrid` to *remove* Refresh button and to use `navButtonAdd` to add [custom button](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) to navigator bar. You can implement any logic inside of `onClickButton` callback and to call `reloadGrid` only if it's really required.

Comment: Thanks. refreshgrid button refreshes wholegrid including search filters everything. but "reloadGrid" doesnt refreshes filters and all correct?

Comment: Is there a code to do the exact refresh button function? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Your idea is great. I just want the code of exact refresh grid function. it refreshes everything. I need it so urgently. Please help. Thanks. @Oleg